# How to use error-message property in vaadin-text-field in angular project with i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization, vaadin

I'm using `vaadin-text-field` in my angular project like this:

```
    <vaadin-text-field
      label="{{ 'full_name' | WgI18n }}"
      formControlName="fullName"
      error-message="{{ 'full_name_error_message' | WgI18n }}"
      ngDefaultControl
    ></vaadin-text-field>
```

And as you can see, the translation is being passed in the same way to both label and error-message. For `label` it works, but for `error-message` it doesn't. And even though the input border becomes red when it's invalid, the error message is not being shown.

It does work if I do something like this:

```
    <vaadin-text-field
      label="{{ 'full_name' | WgI18n }}"
      formControlName="fullName"
      error-message="Enter full name"
      ngDefaultControl
    ></vaadin-text-field>
```

But I need it to be translated.

Comment: It is a String property, so you probably bind it to function that returns a String using locale / language as a key.

Comment: The behavior you describe is the same when the error-message is set to
an empty string.  Can you rule out, that you not just missing the
translation?

Comment: @cfrick yeah I confirm that I'm not missing the translation and even if I am, the fallback is not empty string but rather 'full_name' string untranslated. So it should never be empty